# WinForms use Autofac to RegisterAssemblyTypes from different Project not working

Tags: winforms, autofac

i have winforms and use the following methods (Use Autofac), but not working.

```
static Autofac.IContainer RootContainer1()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new();

        builder.RegisterType<ZFApplication>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<ZFBundle>().SingleInstance();

        //NOT WORKING
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("ZFDataLib.ModelAndInterface"))
            .Where(t => t.Name.StartsWith("I"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

but when i change the method to :

```
static Autofac.IContainer RootContainer2()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new();

        builder.RegisterType<ZFApplication>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<ZFBundle>().SingleInstance();


        //working, but have manually type this 80+ lines
        builder.RegisterType<UserData>().As<IUserData>();
        builder.RegisterType<WarehouseData>().As<IWarehouseData>();
        builder.RegisterType<ValidasiCheckMutasiData>().As<IValidasiCheckMutasiData>();
        builder.RegisterType<TransferRecordData>().As<ITransferRecordData>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

my program can RUN.

my question is, i have 80+ interfaces. and can i use the registerAssemblyTypes to automatically register my interface??

i have 2 projects, with namespace "ZFame" and "ZFDataLib.ModelAndInterface".

appreciate any help

Comment: InnerException = {"None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'ZFDataLib.Model.ZFBundle' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:\r\nCannot resolve parameter 'ZFDataLib.ModelAndInterface.IUserD...

Answer (score -1):

sorry for the noob.

i solved it with this way.

```
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("ZFame"))
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Data"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

the error is with the "Assembly", the assembly load must be the "Namespace" where the data Class Located. not the Interfaces located.

Hope will help someone with multiple project.